# this is my code given below. what is the solution of expected identifier

Tags: ios

there is problem of expected identifier. i want to code in Xcode and feteching problem.

```
UILabel *helloWorldLabel = [UILabel alloc];

if ([helloWorldLabel initWithFrame:[self.view.frame.size.width]] == 320) {
    NSLog(@"ddhsd˙∆˚¬dlkjld");
}

//UILabel *new=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>)];
helloWorldLabel.text = @"My first project";
[helloWorldLabel setText:@"My first project"];
helloWorldLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[helloWorldLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
helloWorldLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
helloWorldLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
helloWorldLabel.layer.borderColor=[UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
helloWorldLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

 [self.view addSubview:helloWorldLabel];
```

Comment: No idea what you are asking!

Comment: Please learn to code properly first. All of your code is completely invalid. StackOverflow is not the right place to begin learning. You are invited to ask questions here once you have a basic understanding of programming, and are stuck on specific, non-trivial problems.

Comment: Sorry. i don't know about this that it is not right place for beginner. can you tell me what is the right place for it?? @duci9y

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the frame of your text as for the if statement, why it exists is beyond me.
add the Following code:

```
helloWorldLabel.frame = CGRectMake([X position of top-left corner here], [Y position of top-left corner here], [how wide you want the object to be], [how tall you want the object to be];
```

For example you you wanted a 300 x 300 box starting at the top left of the screen you would do

```
helloWorldLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 300, 300);
```

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score -3):

This line looks strange to me:

```
[helloWorldLabel initWithFrame:[self.view.frame.size.width]] == 320
```

I guess what you want is:

```
UILabel * helloWorldLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
if (ABS(helloWorldLabel.frame.size.width - 320.0f) < 0.01 )
{
    NSLog(@"ddhsd˙∆˚¬dlkjld");
}
```

If helloWorlLabel is an ivar, you can leave the UILabel * part out, and if it is a property, then you should call

```
self.hellowWorldLabel = ...
```

If all this is still unclear to you, read up on how to create (alloc and init) objects in Objective-C, and what the difference between ivars, properties and local variables are.

Also, comparing floats should not be done with == as it might return NO while expecting YES due to rounding errors. If you type:

```
CGFloat x = 1;
CGFloat y = 1;
if (x == y)
{
    NSLog(@"Equal");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Not equal, x = %f and y = %f", x, y);
}
```

You might see "Not equal..." being printed to the console. This is due to to rounding errors:
x could be 1.0000000000123 and
y could be 1.0000000000012

There, for, you take the absolute value of the difference between two floats and then check this to be under a certain threshold. For UI/pixel related things, less tun 0.01 is usually enough, but your case might be different.

Comment: `self.view.frame.size.width` would be a `CGFloat`, and cannot be used as a `CGRect`. Also, initing and object without allocating memory for it will not work. I do not understand this line of code: `if ((helloWorldLabel.frame.size.width - 320.0f) < 0.01 )`.

Comment: Woops! You're right iff course. Man what did I do there... I giess some copy pasting gone wrong. Changed it to be correct now, thanks.

Comment: `if ((helloWorldLabel.frame.size.width - 320.0f) < 0.01 )` What about this line? Why do write it this way?

Comment: I changed my answer to explain this issue better.